# Javascript Function Only alert if connection type is none

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am using this function below to get the internet connection type

```
function checkConnection() {
        var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

        alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);


}
```

This alerts the state: alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);

What I need to do it get it to alert only if the state is states[Connection.NONE]

I tried:

```
if ((states[networkState]) = states[Connection.NONE]) {
    alert('No internet connection here');
}
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: did you copy paste the code? because you have only one "=" instead of "==" in the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, this

```
if ((states[networkState]) = states[Connection.NONE])
```

Should be

```
if ((states[networkState]) == states[Connection.NONE])
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to remove the function from the if statement.

```
if (networkState == Connection.NONE) {
    alert('No internet connection here');
}
```